# What does it means when put a positive lookahead assertion in the front

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I know `/box(?=.*\d)/` means to match `box` only when there is a digit in the future, but what `/(?=.*\d)box/` means?

I've tested with the string `boxboxOtherTextbox3box` and found the two RegExp matches the same charactors. I feels very confused.

I found this when reading the article :[JavaScript: Password Validation using regular expressions and HTML5](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-password/)

The author uses `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}$/` to ensure the password contains at least one digit; one lowercase; one uppercase; and 6 characters in total.

Answer (score -2):

`/box(?=.*\d)/` matches the first "box" an then tries to assert that there is a number to it's right (which is true because of "3").

`/(?=.*\d)box/` tries to assert that there's a number contained somewhere in the string (which is true because of "3") and then matches the first "box".

The lookahead does not consume characters, it only asserts that a pattern exists (or not). So the "box" pattern of both regex' is applied to (and found at) the start of the string in both cases.